# Vue reactivity issue, need some explanations

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-reactivity

I've removed most useless parts of my code, so don't worry if this code doesn't really make sense, it's just to show you what's not working.

First, I create an array from a base array called `objects`:

```
objects: [
        {
          text: "I dont trigger stuff",
        },
        {
          "text": "I dont trigger stuff",
        },
        {
          text:"I trigger stuff",
          activated: undefined,
        },
],
```

And the create function

```
created() {
    const newArray = [];

    this.objects.forEach(anObj => {
      anObj.activated = false;
      newArray.push(anObj);
    });

    this.filteredObjects = newArray;
},
```

I initialize a property `activated` to `false`. In my real code I'm not using a `forEach`, but a `find` but the result is the same.

Then, I display a few buttons to trigger an "activation"

```
<button
    v-for="(myObj, index) in filteredObjects"
    :key="index"
    @click="activateObject(myObj, index)">
    {{ myObj.text }}
</button>
```

And the function being triggered is this one:

```
activateObject(anObj, anObjIndex) {
      this.$set(this.filteredObjects[anObjIndex], 'activated', !anObj.activated)
},
```

My goal here is just to update the `activated` property.

To check if reactivity is working, I've got a watcher:

```
watch: {
    filteredObjects: {
      handler() {
          alert('called')
      },
      deep: true,
    }
},
```

I've got two questions:

1/ Since all `activated` properties are set to `false` for all objects, why is there only one working, the one with the property initially set to `undefined`?

2/ If I update my activation function to:

```
activateObject(anObj, anObjIndex) {
      anObj.activated = !anObj.activated;
      this.$set(this.filteredObjects, anObjIndex, anObj);
},
```

It works well. Can someone explain me why, and what is the difference?

In both cases, VueJS Devtools shows the updated values when clicking on refresh. It's a reactivity issue.

You can find a fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/dv1jgneb/

Comment: If it's not there at mount, it's not reactive. It's as simple as that. Declare it as empty array in `data()` and you're all set. It's well documented in Vue docs, and it's pretty much the first thing that comes up when searching for "vue reactivity" or the error text you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html):

> Since Vue performs the getter/setter conversion process during instance initialization, a property must be present in the data object in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive.

This explains why only the third button "trigger stuff".

So, you may either add that attribute in the `data()`, or as said in the docs, use `this.$set`:

```
this.objects.forEach(anObj => {
  this.$set(anObj, 'activated', false);
  newArray.push(anObj);
});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gstm436q/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense!